# Do any scriptures mention Vettakkorumakan?

Tags: identification-request, reference-request

I've recently learned about [Vettakkorumakan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vettakkorumakan), the son of Shiva and Parvati. (Also known as a form of Dharma Sastha.)

But, do any scriptures mention him? Possibly with alternative names?

**(Note: You can comment If the scriptures mentions that Shiva-Parvati has son, but he's not popular)**